# jqGrid - How can i disable column draggable but can sortable columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

1. I want to disable reordering by dragging the column but jqGrid works sorting columns.
2. OR, I want to enable reordering by dragging the column and having column chooser.

This code is occured error by dragging the column.

```
$(function () {   
    jQuery("#search_datagrid").jqGrid("GridUnload").jqGrid({
        url: '/Search/SearchDataGrid/',
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
        mtype: 'POST',
        postData: {
             search_word: search_word,
             baseLang: baseLang,
             targetLang: targetLang,
             products: products
        },
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 50],
        colNames: columnNames,
        colModel: columnModels,
        shrinkToFit: true,
        height:'auto',
        autowidth: true,
        pager: "#search_pager",
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: "Result",
        subGrid: true,
        sortable: true,
        loadonce: true,
        gridview: true,

        subGridOptions: {
            "plusicon": "ui-icon-triangle-1-e",
            "minusicon": "ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
            "openicon": "ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e"
        },
    })
    .jqGrid('navGrid', '#search_pager', { add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false })
    .jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#search_pager', {
        caption: "Select Columns",
        title: "Select Columns",
        buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator",
        onClickButton: function () {
            jQuery("#search_datagrid").jqGrid('columnChooser');
        }
    })
    .jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
        useColSpanStyle: true,
        groupHeaders: [
          { startColumnName: '' + baseLang, numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: 'Language' },
        ]
    })
});
$(window).resize(function () {
    $("#search_datagrid").setGridWidth($(this).width() - $(this).width() / 10);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid option `sortable: true`, which you use, is responsible for resorting (reordering) of *columns* with respect of drag and drop of column headers. On the other side `sortable: false` property of `colModel` can be used to prevent sorting of *data* in the column by click on the column header. Reordering of columns with respect of `columnChooser` is independent from the above options and properties, but one can use `hidedlg: true` property in `colModel` to prevent displaying some columns in Column Chooser dialog.

Thus, if I correctly understand your problem, you should just remove `sortable: true` of the grid and not specify any `sortable` property inside of `colModel` (the default value of `sortable` property is `true`, which allows sorting of data).

Comment: Although, Reordering by dragging the column not work, disable drag and sorting are works very well. Thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: @lcy: You are welcome! What you mean under "Reordering by dragging the column not work"? Try on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa2.htm). Do you included `jquery-ui.min.js`? Can you see that dragging is started if you use `sortable: true` option of jqGrid? Is the results of column resorting wrong? **Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)?**